# Partial Template Specialization: Why does some of the variables in the partial specialization list different from the primary template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning about partial template specialization from cppreference and I understand that the number of arguments from the partial specialization templates have to match with the primary and the argument list cant be the same to the non specialized argument. However I am getting tripped with the naming of the variables. 
In the code below:

```
template<class T1, class T2, int I>
class A {};            // primary template

template<class T, int I>
class A<T, T*, I> {};  // #1: partial specialization where T2 is a pointer to T1

template<class T, class T2, int I>
class A<T*, T2, I> {}; // #2: partial specialization where T1 is a pointer

template<class T>
class A<int, T*, 5> {}; // #3: partial specialization where T1 is int, I is 5,
                        //     and T2 is a pointer

template<class X, class T, int I>
class A<X, T*, I> {};   // #4: partial specialization where T2 is a pointer
```

I don't understand why T and X are being used instead of T1 like what purpose is there.

Comment: I can't tell you why they did it, but it is legal to do.

Comment: I totally agree, the naming is horrible and gives little to no meaning to those template parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a template specialization, the name you choose for your template arguments are silent-variables. All of the following is *exactly* equivalent:

```
template<class T, class U, int N> class A<T, U, N> { /*...*/ };
template<class U, class T, int N> class A<U, T, N> { /*...*/ };
template<class F, class G, int Z> class A<F, G, Z> { /*...*/ };
template<class OnceUpon, class ATime, int ThereWere> class A<OnceUpon, ATime, ThereWere> { /*...*/ };
```

In particular, the names *you* choose don't have to match the name of the "original" template definition.

---

In the comments, you asked:

> In the code from my question #1 and #3 have 2 and 1 parameter list respectively. Like why not include the other variables that was in the parameter list for the primary template?

This is how *partial* specialization works. But let's backup a bit.

This is a template class:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct X
{};
```

Here is an explicit specialization of it:

```
X<int, int>;
```

Now, let say I want to define a behaviour for `X<T1, T2>` with `T1 == T2`, this means not only `X<int, int>`, but also `X<double, double>`, `X<float&, float&>`, `X<std::string, std::string>`, and all the infinity of those explicit specializations.

To do so, I need to define a partial specialization which depends on one type (the one playing the roles of both `T1` and `T2`). Thus, this specialization will be introduced by `template<class T>`: only one type:

```
template<class T>
struct X<T, T>
{ using type = T; };
```

If you had used two parameters (`template<class T, class WhatToDoWithThatType>`), what would be the use of the second one?

Comment: It may be equivalent from compiler's point of view, but not from programmer's.

Comment: @VTT hence the *choice* the programmer (aka "you") does.

Comment: @YSC Is there a reason you used A in your parameter considering its also the class head name? Also in the third example A is the same as T, B is the same as U? Also I've noticed some people change the number of arguments for the template parameter list for the partial specialization. Do they only include the variable that they want to change and anything unchanged they leave out

Comment: I mean it is strange to call them *exactly* equivalent.

Comment: @newbie_at_linux this is an error from my end, fixed.

Comment: @newbie_at_linux About _"Also I've noticed some people change the number of arguments for the template parameter list for the partial specialization."_. I'd need an example. This might be a completely different question ;)

Comment: @VTT lookup "equivalent" in [`[over.load]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.load), I use the word with the same meaning.

Comment: @YSC In the code from my question #1 and and #3 have 2 and 1 parameter list respectively. Like why not include the other variables that was in the parameter list for the primary template?